# What is `apexCache` and `apexCacheWarmer` in tooling API?

Tags: tooling-api, cache

I was exploring few bits using tooling API, and stumbled upon 2 endpoints that got my attention.

They are

`/services/data/v45.0/tooling/apexCache`

and

`/services/data/v45.0/tooling/apexCacheWarmer`

I tried searching for them in [Tooling API Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm?search_text=cache) and [Tooling Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm?search_text=cache) but found no success. Can someone point what's the use of those?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cast your mind back to Dreamforce 2016 Josh Kaplan did a talk on the new (at the time) apex compiler.  See [Peek Under the Hood of the New Apex Compiler](https://youtu.be/Yc5FrviQqO8?t=738).

It included details on how compiled apex is cached for use on the app servers.
[image]

`ApexCache` and `ApexCacheWarmer` are almost certainly related to that functionality.

---

I checked with Chris Peterson. Further details:

- They are scratch org specific. At least in terms of being exposed by the API.
- They are used by the SFDX test run command to tell if apex is compiled and/or cached. This is taken into account for how long the tests take to run.
- The documentation is coming in the future.

Comment: Top Man. `They are scratch org specific.` interesting I got them in prod and sandbox as well. I thought it is cached apex code for Future/Queuable/Batch to make sure when batch is executing during deployment, they finish in the old version of apex code. Thanks